# UnhandledPromiseRejection in Express.js

Tags: javascript, express

I hope I'm supplying enough information for this question, but I can't understand why my callback function returns Unhandled Promise Rejection when I on purpose want to catch the error:

```
(node:3144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
(node:3144) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm calling the function here in routes:

```
router.route("/home/create")
    .post(Authorization, function(req, res) {

        CreateSnippetResource(req, function(err) {

            if (err) {
                console.log(err.message)
            }

            res.redirect("/home")
        });
    });
```

And the "CreateSnippetResource"-function:

```
(function() {

    let User = require("../../Models/User");
    let Snippet = require("../../Models/Snippet");

    /**
     * Create a new snippet and save it to database
     * @param request
     * @param callback
     */
    module.exports = function(request, callback) {

        callback(
            User.findOne({ user: request.session.Auth.username }, function(err, user) {
                if (err || user === null) {
                    callback("User not found")
                }

                var snippet = new Snippet({
                    title: request.body.snippetName.split(".").shift(),
                    fileName: "." + request.body.snippetName.split(".").pop(),
                    postedBy: user._id,
                    snippet: [{
                        text: " "
                    }]
                });

                snippet.save().then().catch(function(err) {

                    callback(err)
                });
            }))
    };
}());
```

I'm trying to handle the error when title is not entered. I have a validator in my schema-module that looks like this:

```
SnippetSchema.path("title").validate(function(title) {
    return title.length > 0;
}, "The title is empty");
```

And indeed the returned error-message from the callback `CreateSnippetResource` is `The title is empty`. So how come I get this Promise-error?

I'm assuming it has something to do with how I handle the `snippet.save()`, but can't see how it's not handled. Can you please help?

Comment: The first thing you should fix it the incorrect usage of your `callback`  in the error case you call your callback twice. The first call of `callback` (`callback(User.findOne ... )`)  is definitely wrong, there you call your callback with the result of  `User.findOne`, so if an error occurs it will be called in a second time and `res.redirect("/home")` will be executed twice resulting in  `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`. You should remove the first one place your success `callback` here: `snippet.save().then(function() { callback(); return null;} ).catch(`.

Comment: @t.niese As it turns out, I was an idiot, and forgot that I accidently putted it all in the callback. Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 1):

> Why does my callback function return `Unhandled Promise Rejection` when I on purpose want to catch the error?

That will happen when your `callback` throws another exception. This will reject the promise returned by the `.catch(…)` call, and that rejection is nowhere handled.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I was an idiot, and forgot that I accidentally putted the whole function in the callback. The callback is then executed twice, and thus returns Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.